# SQL Server 2008 Join by date getting right values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, date, join

My scenario is not really hard. Basically, I have two tables and I need to join them through a PK and a date, the thing is that salary table has a date per each monthly payment and the second table called bonus has just a date with the annual bonus that has to be linked with salary on the date after declare the year bonus but just until next year bonus.

Knowing that and just you give you an idea this is how you check the tables.
Salary table:

[image]

Sample data:

DateHist;NumSalarie;ValeurMontant;ChargePatronal;ChargesSalariales

2012-10-31 00:00:00.000;1;3519;1322;766,49
2012-11-30 00:00:00.000;1;3519;1322;766,49
2012-12-31 00:00:00.000;1;3519;1322;766,49
2013-01-31 00:00:00.000;1;3519;1395,15;867,84
2013-02-28 00:00:00.000;1;3592,33;1936,78;1157,09
2013-03-31 00:00:00.000;1;3592,33;1423,23;882,85
2013-04-30 00:00:00.000;1;3592,33;1423,23;882,85
2013-05-31 00:00:00.000;1;3592,33;1423,23;882,85
2013-06-30 00:00:00.000;1;3592,33;1423,23;882,85
2013-07-31 00:00:00.000;1;3592,33;1423,23;882,85
2013-08-31 00:00:00.000;1;3592,33;1202,4;765,41
2013-09-30 00:00:00.000;1;3592,33;1385,19;862,52
2013-10-31 00:00:00.000;1;3592,33;1423,23;882,85
2013-11-30 00:00:00.000;1;3592,33;1423,23;882,85
2013-12-31 00:00:00.000;1;3592,33;1423,23;882,85
2014-01-31 00:00:00.000;1;3592,33;1439,35;897,52
2014-02-28 00:00:00.000;1;3592,33;1825,8;1104,15
2014-03-31 00:00:00.000;1;3666,67;2858,27;1656,17
2014-04-30 00:00:00.000;1;3666,67;1468,1;912,89
2014-05-31 00:00:00.000;1;3666,67;1468,1;912,89

Bonus table:

[image]

Sample data:

CodeRubrique;NumSalarie;ValeurMontant;DateHist

1200;1;1267;2013-02-28 00:00:00.000
1200;1;3448,64;2014-03-31 00:00:00.000
1200;1;3633;2015-03-31 00:00:00.000
1200;1;2244;2015-09-30 00:00:00.000
1200;1;4042,84;2016-10-31 00:00:00.000

So, now when I join both tables I do in T-SQL:

```
SELECT 
salpaid.DateHist,
salpaid.NumSalarie,
salpaid.ValeurMontant,
bonus.ValeurMontant AS bonus
FROM
    (select CodeRubrique,NumSalarie,ValeurMontant,DateHist
    FROM table ) salpaid
LEFT JOIN 
    (select CodeRubrique,NumSalarie,ValeurMontant,DateHist
    FROM T_HBNS
    WHERE  CodeRubrique='1200')  bonus
ON salpaid.NumSalarie=bonus.NumSalarie
AND salpaid.DateHist >= bonus.DateHist
```

So, here is my problem. The thing is that the date joins it's not right because the result when a complete the first year bonus and then I'm on a date after the first year bonus I link twice. the previous year bonus and the current one. just to show you guys my output:

[image]

As you can see the payments before line 73 have NULL in the bonus because the first registered bonus was after those dates then between the line 74 and 87 are ok. the nightmare came when I go through second-year bonus because I get a link on the right bonus category but I have another additional link with previous year bonus as you can see in lines after 88.

How should I improve my code to get the right JOIN?

thanks guys

Comment: salary table is missing the headers

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ You also should specify which DBMS you are working with as mysql <> sql server.

Comment: Sample data is best served as DDL+DML. Images are the worst.

Comment: I added @ZoharPeled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you build a CTE with the start and end dates for each bonus, you can outer join to the cte where the DateHist falls between the Begin and End dates of the bonuses

```
WITH Bonus_Ordered AS (
    SELECT  *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [NumSalarie] ORDER BY [DateHist]) Rn
    FROM    Bonus
    WHERE   CodeRubrique = '1200' 
),   

Bonus_Periods AS (
    SELECT  a.*, 
            b.DateHist - 1 AS EndDateHist 
    FROM    Bonus_Ordered a LEFT JOIN Bonus_Ordered b ON a.Rn + 1 = b.Rn
)

SELECT  *
FROM    Salary s
        LEFT JOIN Bonus_Periods bp ON s.NumSalarie = bp.NumSalarie 
             AND s.DateHist BETWEEN bp.DateHist AND bp.EndDateHist
ORDER BY s.DateHist
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0504d4/3)

Comment: Good approach buddy i got it and actually in the join I added within the between a COALESCE(bp.EndDateHist,getdate()) to garantee always cover the right amount up to date!! thanks

Comment: @AndresAngel good catch.. I thought about that last null date when i was testing the cte's, but forgot to fix it in the join. `Bonus_Periods` cte might be a better place to put the `coalesce(b.DateHist - 1, getdate()) AS EndDateHist`

Answer (score 0):

What if you change

salpaid.DateHist >= bonus.DateHist

to

Year(salpaid.DateHist) = Year(bonus.DateHist)